# SSIS Packages with SQL Server Express 2008 R2

Tags: ssis, etl, sql-server-2008-r2

I understand from various questions [[1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15514572/sql-server-2008-express-integration-services)] [[2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/292564/can-i-run-ssis-packages-with-sql-server-express-or-web-or-workgroup-editions)] that SQL Server Express 2008 R2 doesn't support SSIS packages and that there's only primitive support for ad-hoc data imports / exports.

I have already got SQL Server 2008 Client tools (not express version) installed for use with an instance of SQL Server Standard edition.

Will I be able to use BIDS and SSIS to create packages for use between the Standard edition of SQL Server and the Express instance of SQL Server?

Comment: Have you tried? Don't rely on answers to questions that are easily testable. There are plenty of "answers" out there that are completely wrong. Try it. If it doesn't work, then come back and ask: "why doesn't this work? What did I do wrong?" FWIW, I don't see why it wouldn't work.

Comment: @srutzky Thanks for your comment. The reason I haven't tested myself is because this is within a business environment and there is still a cost implication for installing express therefore was hoping to find out prior to investing.

Comment: OK. But I gotta ask: cost implication for a free product? ;-)

Comment: @srutzky Unfortunately our IT support have to install and therefore there will be a cost :(

Comment: Can you install it on your own PC? It only has to exist _somewhere_ on the network in order to be used as a test, somewhere that SSIS running on the server where Standard Edition is running.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need to be clearer on your exact intended setup. That will allow for a better reading of those two linked questions. I would guess that those two links are actually irrelevant. SQL Server Express comes with a stripped down version of SSIS (or can be installed via the Tools or Advanced install), according to Link #2. But yet your question regards "creat[ing] packages for use between the Standard edition of SQL Server and the Express instance of SQL Server" which implies that you have Standard Edition. If that is the case, then you can create and run packages from the BIDS and SSIS that came with Standard Edition, and connect to Express Edition instances to transfer data back and forth. Documentation that says "SQL Server Express 2008 R2 doesn't support SSIS" is not saying that Express cannot be connected to (unless, of course, your testing indicates otherwise).

**EDIT:**
Testing indicated that this did indeed work; creating an SSIS package from BIDS that came with Standard Edition, and running it from Standard Edition, was able to connect to Express Edition. The only caveat is that, as noted by @Gareth in a comment below, "certain functionality won't work, for example History Cleanup, as it's not supported by Express Edition".

Comment: Thanks for your comments. I've decided that I'm going to replicate the setup on a couple of machines (not work ones) and test the results.

Comment: @Gareth Yer welcome and sounds good. I would be shocked if you were not able to connect. An SSIS package created from BIDS installed via Standard Edition and running via SSIS installed from Standard Edition should be able to connect to any data source that can be configured.

Comment: Just to follow this up, I tried using SSIS with a Standard Edition instance as a source and Express Edition destination with no issues at all. Certain functionality won't work for example History Cleanup as it's not supported by express. cheers

Comment: @Gareth Thanks for the follow up :). I have updated my answer with those details.

Comment: @Gareth Also, please don't forget to mark as "accepted". Thanks :).